# Renovar certificado SSL

Tags: ssl, certbot

Estoy intentado renovar el certificado SLL en mi [raspberry-pi](/questions/tagged/raspberry-pi), a través de certbot, pero no consigo hacerlo.

Cuando le escribo

```
certbot renew
```

me vuelca un error

> "No renewals were attempted."

¿A qué puede ser debido?